# vscode compile java error with string unicode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, unicode-string

I have code sample below image (msg ="能"):

```
public class HelloJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "能";
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

When run command line on window it's OK.

```
PS D:\Projects\JavaExample>javac .\src\HelloJava.java
PS D:\Projects\JavaExample>java -cp 'src' 'HelloJava'
能
```

But when run java in vscode it's alway throw error "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote". 
 (It's error when compile in vscode, run command java/javac on window it's ok)

```
PS D:\Projects\JavaExample>  & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'D:\Projects\JavaExample\bin' 'HelloJava'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

        at HelloJava.main(HelloJava.java:3)
```

These is settings.json

```
{
    "[java]": {
        "files.encoding": "shiftjis"
    },
    "java.debug.settings.vmArgs": "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
}
```

I think cause when compile use encoding utf8

```
PS D:\Projects\JavaExample> Get-Content .\src\HelloJava.java -encoding utf8
public class HelloJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "?\";
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

```
PS D:\Projects\JavaExample> Get-Content .\src\HelloJava.java -encoding shift_jis
public class HelloJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "能";
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Change encoding File from shiftjis to UTF-8: Compiler is OK 
But i want keep encoding shiftjis. Is there a way without changing the encoding of the file and still executing the compiler in vscode?
(run normally similar run command on window)

Comment: if you have copy pasted quotes remove and try typing them

Comment: I try typing quotes. It's still errors

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the character of `能` caused this problem.

I have tried some other characters with the encoding of `shiftjis`, only `能` can cause the problem.

If you must use this character, it's suggested to switch to utf-8.